# Django: помогите перевести строки с помощью I18N

Tags: python, django

Привет, я делаю бот для Телеграмм и решил реализовать локализацию. Но не получается, в функцию не возможно передать request, так как во views мы переходим только один раз для запуска бота. Объект message содержит 'language_code' и получаем язык пользователя каждый раз при запуске функции, но сообщения приходят только на 'en'. Как правильно передать 'language_code' что бы оно подхватило нужный язык? Пример, что содержит 'language_code' можете видеть ниже. И да, если просто встать простую строчку во views, то ее локализирует

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
def settinngs(chat_id, message, language_code):
    print(language_code) #ru-UA
    con = lite.connect('db.sqlite3')
    cur = con.cursor()
    sql = "SELECT City, Lang FROM Userprofile WHERE Id={} ".format(chat_id)
    cur.execute(sql)
    result = cur.fetchall()[0]

    keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2, resize_keyboard=True)
    button_change_city = types.KeyboardButton(text=_('Change name city'))
    button_subs = types.KeyboardButton(text=_('Subscriptions'))
    button_change_language = types.KeyboardButton(text=_('Change language'))
    backs_button = types.KeyboardButton(text=_('Back'))
    keyboard.add(button_change_city, button_subs, button_change_language, backs_button)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                     '{}{}\n{}{}'.format(_('Your city: '), result[0].capitalize(), _('Language: '),
                                         result[1]), reply_markup=keyboard)

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'
USE_I18N = True                                            
LANGUAGES = (
    ('ru', 'Russian'),
    ('en', 'English'),
)

LOCALE_PATHS = (
   os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),
)
```

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте заменить `ugettext` на `ugettext_lazy`.

Answer (score 0):

Тут описна порядок определения языка https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-language-preference
Обратите внимание на след. строки:

> Failing that, it looks for a cookie.
>
> The name of the cookie used is set by the LANGUAGE_COOKIE_NAME setting. (The default name is django_language.)
>
> Failing that, it looks at the Accept-Language HTTP header. This header is sent by your browser and tells the server which language(s) you prefer, in order by priority. Django tries each language in the header until it finds one with available translations.

Соответственно вам нужно или установить cookie или использовать header.